# Importing pandas error after install (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am running Python 3.9 on Mac in VS code. I am currently trying to import data from an Excel file, but I receive the following error message when trying to import pandas:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

However, it seems that it is already installed, as seen below, when I run `pip3 install pandas` in my terminal:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.2.0)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you create a **virtual environment** for your app ? if so, maybe you should activate it first and then **re-install** pandas in it. Above, i guess you installed pandas package GLOBALLY outside the virtual environment.of your app

Comment: @cizario. Oh, thank you, I wasn't aware of that. How do I activate a virtual environment?

Comment: `cd` to your **project root folder**, i assume you already created virtual environment using `pyhon3 -m venv venv`, then `. venv/bin/activate` then you should get something similar to `(venv) my_project_folder $ pip list # e.g ..`

Comment: You can activate it running source ```venv/bin/activate```, where venv is the path name your virtual environment.

Comment: @Andreas -What Python interpreter did you choose in the lower left corner of VS Code? And when you type "_pip --version_", what does the VSCode terminal output?

Comment: @JillCheng I am using Python 3.9.0 64-bit and pip 20.2.3 (when writing 'pip3 --version' in the terminal.

Comment: @cizario It works now, thank you!